# Ned syntax error in compound module when running simulation. Unexpected GATES

Tags: omnet++, inet

This is a basic model to implement up to a Network layer - To behave like a switch.

I get an error on line 37. The console prints `Ned Syntax Error`
The OMNeT++ IDE tells me: `syntax error, unexpected GATES, expecting '}' - NED Syntax Problem`

I don't understand why I get this error, nor what to do to fix it.

```java
import inet.linklayer.ieee802154.Ieee802154Mac;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee802154.bitlevel.Ieee802154UwbIrRadio;


// Module to hold application down to Mac layers.
module Node
{
    submodules:
        Communication: Ieee802154UwbIrRadio;
        Link: Ieee802154Mac;
        Net: BroadcastRouting;
    connections:
        radioIn --> Communicataion.radioIn;
        Communication.upperLayerOut --> Link.lowerLayerIn;
        Communication.upperLayerIn <-- Link.lowerLayerOut;
        Link.upperLayerOut --> Net.fromMac;
        Link.upperLayerIn <-- Net.toMac;
    gates: //Error on this line
        input radioIn;
}

//Module to provide coarse routing
simple BroadcastRouting
{
    gates:
        input fromMac;
        output toMac;
}
```

If it is relevant, this module is included in a network with 3 instances of it and 1 instance of a radiomedium.

Answer (score 1):

Move these two lines

```
gates: //Error on this line
    input radioIn;
```

before `submodules:`.

Comment: This still gives the same error but on the new "gates" line

Comment: I moved it to in front of submodules and that has worked now